# how to get multiple variables from function without struct?

Tags: arrays, c, function, matrix, char

I'm writing a code for a task that I have in college, I've written most of the code but I just realised that something in my core function isn't working like I wish. I've tried to troubleshoot it multiple times but I cannot understand why I'm the `char` variables are deleted in the end of the run while the `int` ones stay.

```
void  Analyze() 
{
    char buffer[81];
    char* ptr;
    char* ptr2;
    ptr = 0;
    fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    char* command = strtok_s(buffer, " \t", &ptr);
    printf_s("the command you selcted is %s\n", command);
    char* Matname = strtok_s(NULL, " \t", &ptr);
    printf_s("the name you selcted is %s\n", Matname);
    char* row1 = strtok_s(NULL, "  \t", &ptr);
    printf_s("the rowsize you selcted is %s\n", row1);
    char* col1 = strtok_s(NULL, " \t", &ptr);
    printf_s("the colsize you selcted is %s\n", col1);
    row = strtol(row1, &ptr2, 10);
    col = strtol(col1, &ptr2, 10);
     //  *command = command;
      // *Matname = Matname;
    printf_s("row number is %d, col number is %d", row, col);
    return ;
 }
```

I need to get the `command` name and the `Matname` so after that ill know how to assign it to the matrix. Right now I'm getting for some reason only row and col and I can build a matrix with it.

Like I said, this is the main function in my project, in the end all of the text will not be they're for debugging, I just cannot seem to know why `command` and `Matname` are being deleted.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of function parameters?

Comment: _Scope_ of variables and _function parameters_ are addressed by any beginner-level C programming book. SO is not a replacement for conventional studies.

Comment: To me it's unclear what you mean by: "he char variables are deleted in the end of the run while the int ones stay."... and where do `row`/`col` come from? Global variables?

Comment: The shown code is unhelpful. It does not seem like it can even compile and hence is in conflict with the description of what seems to be undesired runtime behaviour. " char variables are deleted in the end of the run while the int ones stay". Please try for a [mre] demonstrating what you describe.

Comment: Can't tell for sure as the posted code isn't complete but... Isn't it so that `row` and `col` are global variables while `command ` and `Matname` are local variables? if so then global versus local is the answer

Comment: row, col, Matname and command are global variables. the code shown here is the main function that runs on the main.

Comment: Never use global variables and you should save yourself lots of pain in the back.

Comment: Advice:  Don't waffle, get to the point, ask the question.  Don't tell us a story.  You want to return the _value_ of  the strings `command` and `Matname` to the _calling_ function - is that correct?

Comment: What does "variables are deleted" mean? When are they deleted?

Comment: yes, i want to return the value of command and Matname

Comment: To answer the question in the title (the actual question is not all that helpful): You can't return multiple values from a single function in C. Either define a struct that contains a field "matname" and "command", allocate memory for a struct of that type in the function, fill it and return the pointer to it. Alternatively (imo the better way) pass pointers to a command/matname variables to the function and write the values to those variables in the function.

Comment: The point of my earlier comment was that you clarify question by editing and fixing it, not by adding a comment.  All that stuff about variables being deleted or not is nonsense and not really relevant to your question in any case.  Post a new question of you need help with understanding that.

Comment: @lulle - exactly, though you should refrain from answering the question in comments.  If you have an answer, post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The caller should provide buffers to receive the strings, passing the buffers into the function, thus:

```
void Analyse( char* cmd_buffer, size__t cmd_len, 
              char* matname_buffer, size_t matname_len ) ;

int main()
{
    char* command[81] = {0} ;
    char* matname[81] = {0} ;

    Analyse( command, sizeof(command) - 1, 
             matname, sizeof(matname) - 1 ) ;
}


void Analyse( char* cmd_buffer, size__t cmd_len, 
              char* matname_buffer, size_t matname_len )
{
    ...

    strncpy( cmd_buffer, command, cmd_len ) ;
    strncpy( matname_buffer, Matname, matname_len ) ;

    return ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, functions can not return multiple values. You basically have two options:

- Pass buffers to the function, fill the provided buffers with the relevant data (see Clifford's answer).
- Allocate buffers in the function and return pointers to said buffer.

For the latter, you can do something like this:

```
void foo(char **p_cmd_buffer, char ** p_matname_buffer){
    ...
    *p_cmd_buffer = malloc(cmd_buffer_required_size);
    if(p_cmd_buffer != NULL){
        //copy your data to the buffer
    }
    *p_matname_buffer = malloc(cmd_buffer_required_size);
    if(p_matname_buffer != NULL){
        //copy your data to the buffer
    }
    ...
}

int main(void){enter code here
    ...
    char *cmd, *matname;
    foo(&cmd, &matname);
    ...
}
```

Alternatively you can wrap your data in a struct, allocate one in your function, fill it and return a pointer to it:

```
struct wrapper_struct{
    char *matname;
    char *cmd;
}

struct wrapper_struct* foo(void){
    ...
    struct wrapper_struct* ret = malloc(sizeof(struct wrapper_struct));
    if(ret != NULL){
        ret->cmd = malloc(cmd_buffer_required_size);
        if(ret->cmd != NULL){
            //copy your data to the buffer
        }
        ret->matname = malloc(matname_buffer_required_size);
        if(ret->matname){
            //copy your data to the buffer
        }
    }
} 

int main(void){
    ...
    wrapper_struct* data = foo();
    ...
}
```

This is only really useful if the calling function doesnt know, how big the buffers have to be. In your case, the size is known (81 chars per string).

Disadvantages:

- The calling function may not know, how the memory was allocated. You have to provide additional functions to free the data again.
- You have to deal with potential failure to allocate memory